# Best way to load highcharts.js ? Highcharts error #16

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, highcharts

I am first rendering a view called 'Index' which has various ajax buttons on. I click a ajax button which then loads a partial view called 'SpamStatsPVW' into a div in 'Index'. Once this partial view has been loaded it then loads another partial view called 'spamStatsContent' into a div in 'SpamStatsPVW'

spamStatsContent contains my highcharts function which build the charts. The first time this works fine but if I press the refresh ajax button in the 'SpamStatsPVW' it give me highcharts error #16.

I am loading the highcharts.js in the '_layout' view used by all pages. What is the best way to load this so I do not get this error ?

Note: I already have a charts page which work fine and I do not encounter this error. Again it has a view called 'Index' which then inserts the partial view 'statsContent' into a div in 'Index'

Why does this chart work fine ?

Comment: In your browser console you can click on the error and it takes you to a page that explains what that ***Highcharts error #16*** means exactly

Comment: I already know what the error means, I want to know the best way to load the highcharts.js file

Comment: Are you using sharepoint? your _layouts folder points me towards this assumption

Comment: @RononDex No i am not using share point, it is a MVC 3 application

Comment: Only load it once in some master Index call that is not used by any other views.

Comment: It seems that you load highcahrts twice or highcharts and highstock.js So check this issue